# Where to put Coherence configuration files?

Tags: oracle-coherence

I found lots of document talking about Oracle Coherence cluster configuration bur did't know where to put it, default configuration files location in coherence.jar but I don't think these files meant to be modified, I am using coherence with Weblogic 12c

Comment: I don't understand the question, what are you trying to accomplish? What problems are you having? The coherence.jar is not meant to be modified, you should reference it as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLCOH/deploy-wls-coherence.htm#WLCOH768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer it should be put on the class path of the application, files with postfix override like **tangosol-coherence-override.xml** should override default configuration in coherence.jar